# Webpack: serve static (local) file for a dev website

Tags: webpack

sorry if my question is too silly.
I'm trying to move from gulp to webpack for the production of our assets (sass/js/img).
I little premise: We develope site in php, not in js, so much of the doc I found is not for my case (I also know that is a nonsense, use webpack only as task runner is not the best way and his purpose).

Following tutorial I already compiled my resource and write the script to watch the update of the assets.

My webpack.config.js (you can skip it, is only for a broad vision)

```
module.exports = {
entry: ["./assets/scripts/script.js", "./assets/styles/styles.scss"],
output: {
    filename: "scripts/scripts.min.js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "./dist/")
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(otf|eot|ttf|woff|svg|png|jpe?g)/i,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "url-loader",
                    options: {
                        name: "./assets/images/[name].[ext]",
                        limit: 10000
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: "img-loader"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {minimize: true}
                    },
                    {loader: "postcss-loader"},
                    {loader: "sass-loader"}
                ]
            })
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ["env"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: "styles/styles.min.css"
    }),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true
    })
]
};
```

Now I want serve and browser-sync my compiled assets (js/css) to a dev website hosted on the web in order to speed up the develop of the scripts and style.

I tried in this way (and other way, but this is the one seems close to the solution), adding the devServer param to module.exports

```
devServer: {
    quiet: false,
    stats: {colors: true},
    proxy: {// proxy URLs to backend development server
        '/': {
            target: 'http://my.site.it',
            secure: false,
            "protocol": 'http:',
            "port": 80
        },
        ignorePath: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false
    },
    overlay: {
        warnings: true,
        errors: true
    },
    disableHostCheck: true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '../../../../../../../httpdocs'), // boolean | string | array, static file location        
    //port: 3000,
    hot: true, // hot module replacement. Depends on HotModuleReplacementPlugin
    https: false, // true for self-signed, object for cert authority
    open: true,
    //useLocalIp: true,
    noInfo: false // only errors & warns on hot reload
}
```

I think I miss some configuration cause I have a strange behaviour.
I have the online site served on my http://localhost, but it seems that he can't resolve the virtual host, because I obtain the dummy page you obtain by inserting the server ip address in the url, and not the correct site called by my.site.it

I know that is a very singolar question, but I hope someone know the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution according with the server assistant

When server responde to multiple vhost, if you proxy the content you have to pass an header with the site you are requesting.

I added this line

```
proxy: {// proxy URLs to backend development server
    '/': {
        target: 'http://my.site.it',
        secure: false,
        "protocol": 'http:',
        "port": 80,
         headers: {
                "Host": "my.site.it"
         }
    },
    ignorePath: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false
},
```